# ¿Se puede acceder a la entrada de un diccionario sin escribir la clave en el template de django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

Voy a tratar de explicarlo con el siguiente ejemplo

Utilizando Django 3.0, dada una vista cualquiera, envío como contexto el siguiente diccionario al template

```
{
'sumary': { 'usuarios': 15,
            'articulos': 1,
            'autores': 7},
'name_entry': get_entry_name()
}
```

La función `get_entry_name()` devuelve alguno de las tres cadenas `'usuarios'`, `'articulos'` o `'autores'`

Ahora, dentro del template, se que para acceder a las entradas del diccionario `sumary` uso la siguiente sintaxis:

```
{{sumary.usuarios}}
{{sumary.articulos}}
{{sumary.autores}}
```

**La pregunta puntual**

**¿Puedo acceder a las entradas del diccionario con el valor de la variable `name_entry`?**

```
{{sumary.name_entry}}
```

lo que seria el equivalente en código de python

```
sumary[name_entry]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente eso no se puede hacer en [**el lenguaje de plantilla Django**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#the-django-template-language-for-python-programmers), pues las [variables y búsquedas](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) funcionan así:

> Los puntos tienen un significado especial en la representación de
> plantillas. Un punto en el nombre de una variable significa una
> búsqueda. Específicamente, cuando el sistema de plantillas encuentra
> un punto en el nombre de una variable, intenta las siguientes
> búsquedas, en este orden:
>
> - Búsqueda de diccionario. Ejemplo: `foo["bar"]`
> - Búsqueda de atributos. Ejemplo: `foo.bar`
> - Búsqueda de índice de lista. Ejemplo: `foo[bar]`

Entonces, eso tendrías que hacerlo en la vista misma:

```
dict = {
    'sumary': { 
        'usuarios': 15,
        'articulos': 1,
        'autores': 7
    },
}

dict['result'] = dict['sumary'][get_entry_name()]
```

Entonces tu diccionario seria algo así:

```
{'sumary': {'usuarios': 15, 'articulos': 1, 'autores': 7}, 'result': ?}
```

Y simplemente usas la variable de contexto `result` (`<p>{{ result }}</p>`).

Por otra parte podrías hacer algo así en el template:

```
{% if name_entry == 'usuarios' %}
    {{ sumary.usuarios }}
{% elif name_entry == 'articulos' %}
    ...
...
{% endif %}
```

Pero no me parece optimo, el primer método es mejor. Espero haberte ayudado.